# Messaging using Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am trying to make a simple messaging app and have this code which I think should work....

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  messaging test
//
//  Created by 23AthreyaDaniel on 7/5/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 23AthreyaDaniel. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MessageUI
class ViewController: UIViewController,MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate{
    func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    }

    @IBAction func send(_ sender: Any) {
        if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText(){
            let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            controller.body = "test"
            controller.recipients = ["6507984792"]
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
            self.present(controller,animated: true,completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            print("can't send it")
        }
      func  messageComposeViewController(){
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

However it keeps going to the else loop and saying that the message cannot be sent. What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although my code is correct, apple does not allow texting to be done on simulators, hence the boolean in my first if statement `"MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()"` always being False. If I had run this same code on an actual apple device with a developer liscence it would have worked.